# Jquery Ajax Submitting/Retrieving

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have never really used Jquery before and I am wondering what your opinions of it is when using it for Ajax purposes. I need to submit a form on a page without reloading the page then load the submitted data along with other data in a div as new data arrives, think something similar to a chatroom as the functionality is about the same.

Do you think I should use Jquery or should I look at something else/code from scratch? I am trying to make my sites more dynamic and less static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, jQuery is the best javascript library when it comes to parse and manipulate a HTML document. It also supports Ajax and it's very easy to use. One other big advantage is that works across a multitude of browsers, so you write your code once and will work on all 5 major browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari).

So I'd recommend you to use jQuery and AJAX for improving your website.

Answer (score 0):

`Imagine` ..After you ping some one and  the whole page refresh and got the reply from your mate .How sad :(

`Ajax` has changed the web. There’s no doubt about that. It’s made the internet a happier place to be (well, when it’s used well) and has helped fuel the `Web 2.0 movement` to make it what it is `today`.

My suggetion is **JUST GO FOR IT.**

Comment: I was asking if you think Jquery a good library to use for ajax.

Comment: Yes and Jquery is  mostly using java script library .So you can get more support for further.Sorry for not mentioning that in my answer .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use jquery in your project. it is very simple to use it. and You have to defiantly use Ajax using jquery or javascript. because using Ajax webpage use resources what they needs. and Loading time also will be minimized.